# What is the best way to convert Querystring values to XML tags in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a query string value.
The query string is "a=1&b=2&c=3"
I want to convert this to 

< Qurystring>
< a >1
< b >2< /b>
< c>3< /c>"
< /Querystring>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer using XDocument.

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("xmlFile.xml"));

XElement xmlTree = new XElement("Parent");

```
            foreach (String key in Request.Form)
            {
                xmlTree.Add( new XElement(key, Request.Form[key]));

            }
            xmlTree.Save("xmlFile.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Details:** here is the solution to your question. Please Tick if it solves your question

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateXML();
}

public void CreateXML()
{
    // Get query strings
    string a = Request.QueryString["a"];
    string b = Request.QueryString["b"];
    string c = Request.QueryString["c"];

    if (a != null && b != null && c != null)
    {
        string directoryPath = Server.MapPath("~/XMLFiles/");

        string fileName = "QueryString.xml";

        if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
        }

        //Start writer
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(directoryPath + fileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        //Start XM DOcument
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.Indentation = 2;

        //ROOT Element
        writer.WriteStartElement("Querystring");

        //call create nodes method
        createNode(a, b, c, writer);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        //End XML Document
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        //Close writer
        writer.Close();
    }
}

private void createNode(string a, string b, string c,  XmlTextWriter writer)
{
    //a
    writer.WriteStartElement("a");
    writer.WriteString(a);
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    //b
    writer.WriteStartElement("b");
    writer.WriteString(b);
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    //c
    writer.WriteStartElement("c");
    writer.WriteString(c);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```